# Why does this F18 have the rudders pointing towards each other?

Tags: military, flight-controls, fighter

I have seen this when they are parked and when taking off from the carriers.

[image: F18 hornet]

Comment: [Because ground effect was not considered during development.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19214/why-are-the-f-a-18-rudders-deflected-in-opposing-directions-during-takeoff/35867?r=SearchResults&s=1|69.2638#35867)